# Vue.js how can i loop throw an array to add components to the dom according to array items

Tags: vue-component

I am making an app that communicate with an api and fetch data,home page changes every day so i can't just add static components to it,
i need to create it according to the data that comes from the api.

i have a component for the home page called `Home.vue`

this component can have one or more **Carousels** depending on the data that i'am fetching.

i also have `Carousel.vue` which is responsible about displaying images and it had it's own `props`.

the question is :

**How to add component to the dom from loop**

this is `Home.vue` where i am making the `loop` :

```
    <template>
      <div>
    
    
        <!--I Need The Loop right here-->
    
    
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    
      export default {
        components: {},
        data() {
          return {
            page_content: [],
            widgets: [],
    
          }
        },
        created() {
          this.getHomeContent();
        },
        methods:
          {
    
            getHomeContent() {
              window.axios.get(window.main_urls["home-content"]).then(response => {
                this.page_content = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data));
                console.log(this.page_content);
                for (let index in this.page_content) {
                  switch (this.page_content[index].type) {
    //                if type is banner
                    case 'banner':
                      switch (this.page_content[index].display) {
    //                    if display is carousel
                        case 'carousel':
                          console.log('carousel')
                          // end if display is carousel
                          this.widgets.push({
                            'type': 'Carousel',
                            'images': this.page_content[index].items,
    
                          })
                      }
    
    //                  end if type is banner
    
                  }
                }
    
              });
            }
          }
      }
    </script>
```

and this is `Carousel.vue` which i need to be imported when needed **with passing props** :

```
    <template>
    <div>
        <div >
          <VueSlickCarousel>
            <div v-for="image in images">
              <img src="{{img}}">
            </div>
          </VueSlickCarousel>
        </div>
    </div>
    </template>
    <script>
      import VueSlickCarousel from 'vue-slick-carousel'
      import 'vue-slick-carousel/dist/vue-slick-carousel.css'
    
      import 'vue-slick-carousel/dist/vue-slick-carousel-theme.css'
      export default
      {
        components: {VueSlickCarousel},
        name:'Carousel',
        props:[
    
          'images'
        ],
    
        methods:
          {
    
          }
      }
    </script>
```

how to add `Carousel.vue` component to `Home.vue` dynamically *some thing like*:

```
if(data.display == 'carousel')
{
   <carousel images="data.images"></carousel>
}
```

Comment: Use the component and add a `v-for` to loop through the array?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen how ?

Answer (score 0):

Import the component to your Home.vue :

```
import Carousel from './Carousel.vue'

export default {
    components: {Carousel},
}
```

Then loop in your template:

```
<carousel v-for="(widget,index) in widgets" :key="index" :images="widget.images"/>
```

Best to use a widget.id rather than index for the `key` prop

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct answer !

```
    <template>
      <div>


        <template v-for="widget in widgets">

          <div v-if="widget.type == 'carousel'" :key="widget.type">
            <carousel
              :images="widget.images"
              :arrows ="widget.arrows"
              :dots = "widget.dots"
            >

            </carousel>
          </div>

        </template>


      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
      import Carousel from './widgets/Carousel.vue'
      export default {
        components: {Carousel},
        data() {
          return {
            page_content: [],
            widgets: [],

          }
        },
        created() {
          this.getHomeContent();
        },
        methods:
          {

            getHomeContent() {
              window.axios.get(window.main_urls["home-content"]).then(response => {
                this.page_content = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data));
                console.log(this.page_content);
                for (let index in this.page_content) {
                  switch (this.page_content[index].type) {
    //                if type is banner
                    case 'banner':
                      switch (this.page_content[index].display) {
    //                    if display is carousel
                        case 'carousel':
                          console.log('carousel')
                          // end if display is carousel
                          this.widgets.push({
                            'type': 'carousel',
                            'arrows':true,
                            'dots':true,
                            'images': this.page_content[index].items,
                          })
                      }

    //                  end if type is banner

                  }
                }

              });
            }
          }
      }
    </script>
```